# How to encrypt-decrypt payload/data in node-api and angular both end?

Tags: node.js, angular, cryptography

I am developing a MEAN stack app. Where I want to encrypt and decrypt REST API data/payload in HTTP-Interceptor. On the other hand in my node.js rest API want to decrypt-encrypt req, res in some middleware. I found crypto, node-forge, and others but didn't find a proper example. Even are those safe to use and work perfectly or not. Can anyone suggest the right package and example for implement on both ends?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use https and why that won't suffice? or do you want to encrypt the data obtained from the request to the server before processing it further?

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I think the question was to know if there is package that can encrypt/decrypt the response to and from server.Such that if any one tries to read the data from network(dev tools) they wouldn't understand the info in the response or payload.

Comment: The attacker model seems slightly strange here. With devtools you're assuming that the client who receives the message cannot see the message on the wire but knows the decryption key to decrypt the message? So how does having an encrypted response which is decrypted locally make a difference? If you're worried about on-path adversaries sniffing network traffic for payload information, https solves that for you? OP should clarify what the intent is and what they're trying to implement.